# What is the meaning of the elevator scene in Zero Dark Thirty?

Tags: plot-explanation, zero-dark-thirty

The CIA Director enters an elevator with someone and asks about Jessica Chastain's character.

The assistant claims she is really smart, to which the Director responds with, "We're all smart".

What is the significance of this sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that it's not about being smart..

**It's about knowing what you are talking about and and having the guts to hold a position.**

We see, in the scene prior to the elevator sequence, that the other CIA officials are all hedging their bets about the location of Bin Laden, Chastain's character is the only one who will commit to being *certain*.

This is why, even though, all of them are smart... **he discounts that as being the deciding factor**. Being knowledgeable, and committed to an opinion, even an internally unpopular one, carries more weight with him

Which is why, in the very next scene, the Director talks to Chastain's character to weigh her up for himself.

He's convinced, not only by her certainty but by the fact that the only thing she's done for the CIA in her 12 years...is hunt Bin Laden.